# Creating a todo list using firebase, confused trying to understand the logic

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Creating a todo list using firebase, confused trying to understand the logic behind it please see the main actitivty below.\Creating a todo list using firebase, confused trying to understand the logic behind it please see the main actitivty below.Creating a todo list using firebase, confused trying to understand the logic behind it please see the main actitivty below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<ToDo> toDoList = new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseFirestore database;
//
    RecyclerView listItem;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FloatingActionButton fab;

    public MaterialEditText title,description;
    public boolean isUpdate = false;
    public String idUpdate = " ";

    ListItemAdapter adapter;
    SpotsDialog dialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //i think the issue is here
        listItem = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listTodo);
        listItem.setHasFixedSize(true);


        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        listItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);





            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!isUpdate){
                    setData(title.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString());
                }
                else{
                    updateData(title.getText().toString(),description.getText().toString());
                    isUpdate = !isUpdate; //this resets it
                }
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle().equals("DELETE"))
            deleteItem(item.getOrder());
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }





    private void loadData() {
        dialog.show();
        if (toDoList.size() > 0)
            toDoList.clear();
        database.collection("ToDoList")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                        //end of oncomplete section added
                        for (DocumentSnapshot doc:task.getResult())
                        {
                            ToDo todo = new ToDo(doc.getString("id"),

                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_info"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:background="#1190CB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
                app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
                app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
                app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true" />
            <!--add more for card items -->
            <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
                app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
                app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
                app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate` of your activiy, try to first init the layoutManager and only then link it to the recyclerView:

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
listItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Another option is to declare it in the xml file:

```
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listTodo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

and then you won't have to do anything programmatically.

**Update from comment:**

Your app is crashing with `NullPointerException` because you don't initiate `todoList` in your adapter's constructor, so the `getItemCount()` is called when your list is null.

Add a check in that method, in the adapter class:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (todoList != null)
        return todoList.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added in both to the app and its stopped crashing upon opening , however when clicking the fab button it then crashes with error;    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at e.marc.managementapplication.Adapter.ListItemAdapter.getItemCount(ListItemAdapter.java:101)

Comment: This is because you don't initiate `todoList` in your adapter's constructor! so the `getItemCount()` is called when your list is null

Comment: Hi sorry, can you tell me where to write this in the code please?

Comment: Hi, That has stopped it crashing but i am still getting the E/RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout, i have updated my mainactivity code and added the xml file. hopefully this helps to find the issue! also thank you so much for your help already

Comment: Does your `recyclerview` populating with items properly?

Comment: the recylerview doesnt display anything if thats what you are asking?

Comment: And are you sure you actually get valid data from firebase in `loadData()`?

Comment: I am unsure how to check that, it just says from firebase that it is being read

Comment: are you able to help with this please?

Comment: If the code you posted here is whole, it seems that in `ListItemAdapter` constructor you don't save the references of `mainActivity` and `toDoList`. I believe that is why the `recyclerview` isn't displaying anything, it just has nothing to display.

Comment: so everything i have included (mainactivity, todo model and the adapter) is everything included in his youtube video. Can i send you over my github and you can have a look at my issues ?

Comment: Please try to add `this.mainActivity = mainActivity;` and `this.toDoList = toDoList;` at `ListItemAdapter`'s constructor

Comment: i have added this;  public ListItemAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<ToDo> toDoList) {
           this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }             Is this what you mean? however "this.toDoList = toDoList;" is not excepted when placed underneath is this where you mean? if you could give direct code it would be more useful to me sorry

Comment: Man there are **2** paramters at the `ListItemAdapter`'s constructor. You need to **save them both** if you want the adapter to actually work. I don't know what you mean by "not expected when placed underneath".

Comment: I have placed "this.mainActivity = mainActivity;" in the Public ListItemAdapter. I am unsure of where the other constructor is that you want me to put " this.toDoList = toDoList;"     I have placed it inside all brackets and it turns up red reagrdless of where i am putting it

Comment: I have added into the mainactivity database.collection a make toast that shows me the data is being called back it is just not displaying

Comment: Glad to hear. What was the problem?

Comment: an absolute ton when i posted, however it was a capital letter on the this.toDoList = toDoList;" soon as that changed it worked hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You missing setting layout manager for your recycler view. You have commented creating him

```
listItem.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, where about should i insert this?

Comment: Just uncomment line `//        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
` in `MainActivity` before `ListViewAdapter` and delete line below `listItem.setLayoutManager(manager);`

Comment: Hi, I have changed it so it looks like this   
  
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        adapter = new ListItemAdapter(MainActivity.this,toDoList);
        listItem.setAdapter(adapter);
        listItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
//        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);  but i still get the same  error code as above

Answer (score 0):

remove the loadData() inside of the loadData().

Comment: This has now stopped the fab button crashing but still the recylerview is beign skipped, here are the errors;       2019-04-11 07:30:15.430 17533-17543/? E/mentapplicatio: Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe
2019-04-11 07:30:17.950 17533-17533/e.marc.managementapplication E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: do you know how to fix this, i have updated my code and yet it still says i am getting the error with recyclerview

Comment: remove import e.marc.managementapplication.R; in adapter and check your package name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the layout manager this way.

```js
        listItem = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listTodo);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        listItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        listItem.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Try to use the firebase recycler view, will help you to manage the new items, updates and etc.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android